# Equivariant maps inducing isomorphism in integral cohomology

Tags: at.algebraic-topology, gt.geometric-topology, reference-request

Consider the following statement.

Suppose $X$, $Y$ are finite CW-complexes with free involution
and $\mu:X\to Y$ is an equivariant map.
If $\mu^*:H^i(Y;\mathbb{Z})\to H^i(X;\mathbb{Z})$ is an isomorphism for $i>i_0$
and is onto for $i=i_0$, then $\mu^{\sharp}:\pi_{\mathrm{eq}}^i(Y)\to\pi_{\mathrm{eq}}^i(X)$
is a 1-1 correspondence for $i>i_0$ and is onto for $i=i_0$.

Moreover, the preimage of each element of $\pi_{\mathrm{eq}}^{i_0}(X)$
is in 1-1 correspondence with the elements of
the kernel of
$\mu^*:H^{i_0}(Y;\mathbb{Z})\to H^{i_0}(X;\mathbb{Z})$.

Here $\pi_{\mathrm{eq}}^i(Y)$ denotes the set of all equivariant maps $Y\to S^i$ up to equivariant homotopy.
This statement, without the 'moreover' part, appears to be known. Becker and Glover in *Note on the embedding of manifolds in euclidean space* (1971) state it
(without the 'moreover' part) and claim that it is well known from obstruction theory. But what about the `moreover' part: is it true? if yes, can you give a reference?

Answer (score 1):

I don't know of a reference off-hand but here's one way to think about it. First, one can think of $H^i(X;\mathbb{Z})$ as $[X,K(\mathbb{Z},n)]$, the set of homotopy classes of maps. Notice that a cellular model for $K(\mathbb{Z},n)$ can be taken to be $S^n$ union higher cells that kill off the higher homotopy groups. Second, any map $f:X\to Y$ can be replaced by an inclusion $\iota:X\to M_f$, where $M_f$ is the mapping cylinder and it has the same homotopy type as that of $Y$. This works in the equivariant setting also. The third fact is that if any equivariant map $f:X\to Y$ induces an isomorphism in cellular cohomology and $f$ acts freely on both $X$ and $Y$ then $f$ induces an isomorphism on equivariant cohomology as well. The equivariant cohomology can be thought of as maps from spaces to $K(\mathbb{Z},n)$ up to equivariant homotopy.

Now think of $f:X\to Y$ as in inclusion and there is a long exact sequence in cohomology
$\cdots\to H^\ast(X;\mathbb{Z})\to H^{\ast+1}(Y,X;\mathbb{Z})\to H^{\ast+1}(Y;\mathbb{Z})\to H^{\ast+1}(X;\mathbb{Z})\to H^{\ast+2}(X;\mathbb{Z})\to\cdots$
which tells you in your case that $H^{i}(Y,X;\mathbb{Z})=0$ if $i>i_0$. The kernel of $H^{i_0}(Y;\mathbb{Z})\to H^{i_0}(X;\mathbb{Z})$ is just the image of $H^{i_0}(Y,X;\mathbb{Z})$ in $H^{i_0}(Y;\mathbb{Z})$. Thinking of $H^{i_0}(Y,X;\mathbb{Z})$ as relative homotopy classes of maps from $(Y,X)$ to $K(\mathbb{Z},i_0)$. These maps only probe the $i_0$ skeleton of $(Y,X)$ because $H^i(Y,X;\mathbb{Z})=0$ if $i>i_0$. And since any map can be made homotopic to a cellular map we need only study homotopy classes of maps from the $i_0$-skeleton of $(Y,X)$ to the $i_0$-skeleton of $K(\mathbb{Z},i_0)$ which is $S^{i_0}$. These are precisely the different ways of factoring a given equivariant map $X\to S^{i_0}$ via $X\stackrel{f}{\to} Y\to S^{i_0}$ (all upto equivariant homotopy).